# Let $ f:I \to \mathbb{R} , I=(0,1) $ be uniformly continuous. Then exists $ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac{1}{n}) $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, limsup-and-liminf, uniform-continuity

True.

Since $f$ is continuous (because all uniformly continuous function is continuous), we can assume:

$$ f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\right) $$

Since $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} $ is bounded in $ (0,1] $ and $ I \subset (0,1] $, we have by hypothesis $f$ uniformly continuous then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \text{, exists.} $$

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: By the way: $f(\lim 1/n)$ is not defined.

Comment: @muaddib My question is. Is that correct?

Comment: Use the fact that uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @Andre, if isn't defined. Therefore is false, we can conclude that my "proof" is incorrect. That is what you meant?

Comment: Indeed, $f(\text{lim} \frac{1}{n})$ is not defined yet. But using the end of your argument, you know that $\text{lim} f(\frac{1}{n})$ is bounded and which will allow you to define $f(0)$

Comment: @DavidMitra are you giving me another way to think about it or affirming that my method was flawled?

Comment: Why would you want to define $f(0)$ ? I also don't understand what you mean by "We can assume $f(\lim 1/n)$". And what do you mean by $\lim 1/n$ is bouned ? Can a limit be unbounded ?

Comment: Sorry. Your method makes no sense to me.

Comment: djvyu72, isn't defined because the question try to cover all uniformly continuous functions. Is there anything I can write to make my "proof" better written? 

I got this question from an analysis exam. Trying to solve them.

Comment: @andre limits are always bounded, that is true, but it should be bounded outside the domain of $f$, if that happens, I could not say anything about the affirmative.

When I talk about the bounderies, I'm talking about the $limsup$ and $liminf$ of $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Both, $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are the $\lim$ which is $0$.

Comment: @Andre, that is true. My bad. If lim exists limsup=liminf. You're correct.

I meant $\sup$ and $\inf$.

Comment: Does this question deserve a -1? I read somewhere that -1 (or lower) questions are deleted. How can I improve to make this question better evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as David says: To prove your claim it is sufficient to prove that the sequence $(f(1/n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy. Completeness of $\mathbb R$ will then give you the desired convergence. To see that the sequence is Cauchy let $\epsilon > 0$ and note that, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert < \epsilon$, whenever $\lvert x-y \rvert  < \delta$. For $m,n$ big enough (such that $\lvert 1/n - 1/m \rvert  = \lvert (m-n)/(mn) \rvert < \delta$), it follows that 
$$
\lvert f(1/n) - f(1/m) \rvert < \epsilon
$$ for large enough $m,n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* You are trying to prove that $f$ can be extended to $[0,1)$ by putting $f(0)=\lim f(\frac{1}{n})$.

By uniform continuity of $f$ you can prove that limit exists (how?), and therefore $f$ can be extended in a coherent way (a way that makes that $f$ continuous in $[0,1)$ )

Comment: I think, I'm not trying to prove that. Because by hypothesis the functions is  uniform continuous just in the open interval $(0,1)$, I cannot say anything about $[0,1)$.

Comment: By proving that sequence is Cauchy (see Andre's answer) you also prove what I said

Comment: I will think about that. Thank you/.

Comment: In fact. I just found the theorems about this, and one that states exactly what you affirmed: Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R} $ be uniform continuous. For all $a \in X' $ (where ' denotes the set derivative), exists $ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) $.